# Combine some of all columns

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am trying to return information from a table (called addresses) with several columns.  The physical address is divided into line1, line2, city, state, etc.  I want to display all columns in the table, but want to combine the line1 and line2 columns into a single column named street.

Is there a way to do this without listing every single column on the table?

Comment: You can also use concat() [refer this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT Line1 + ',' + Line2, city, state From Address
```

**(Or)**

```
SELECT concat(line1, ' , ', line2) , city, state From Address
```

Comment: Your second suggestion is close to what I was trying originally.  I have two other columns before line1.  I would like to not have to list every single column but still use CONCAT to combine the two columns for the address.  Here is the code I have typed:

SELECT address_id, customer_id, CONCAT(line1, ' ', line2) AS Street, city, state, zip_code, disabled
 FROM addresses;

Comment: Yes, it works OK.  I was just wondering if there was a way to be a little more efficient since I am displaying every column on the table.  I tried this also:

SELECT *, CONCAT(line1, ' ', line2) AS street FROM addresses;

This list the entire table and additionally adds the street column to the end.

Comment: You need to call separate columns. your idea won't work here.. Mark useful if it's helped

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT line1 + line2 AS street, city, state FROM addresses
```

Comment: With a little modification I was able to get a bit closer.  However, I have two other columns before line1 and line2.  Here is the code I entered before:

SELECT address_id, customer_id, CONCAT(line1, ' ', line2) AS Street, city, state, zip_code, disabled
 FROM addresses;

Is there a way to not have to list all of the columns I need but also use CONCAT for line1 and line2?

Comment: I do not think so, you can use CONCAT but you have to list anyway the columns you want to show. Well you can do `SELECT CONCAT(line1, '', line2), * FROM ...` but you are going to get line1, line2 as well and also using * is less efficient.

Comment: I actually tried this:

SELECT *, CONCAT(line1, ' ', line2) AS street FROM addresses;

The way you suggested gave me an error.  However, the way I entered the code from this reply lists all the columns and adds another named street at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT Line1 + ',' + Line2 as Street, city, state From [TableName]
```